# Tkinter: pickle data from Entry

Tags: python, tkinter, pickle

I currently have my application set to gather data from all the entries on the page with a button widget. The function that is set to the buttons command should save the inputted info. How do I make sure that data is actually being saved, how do I load the data, lastly how do I get my button to run two commands, as I am trying to show a new page once the button is pressed.

This is the function

```
def set_streak(self):
        current = self.current
        day = self.day
        hour = self.hour
        minute = self.minute
        action = self.action
        streak_num = self.action_num

        file = open("streak_data", "wb") # opens the file

        pickle.dump(self.get_action, file)
        pickle.dump(self.get_streak_num, file)
        pickle.dump(current, file)
        pickle.dump(self.get_day, file)
        pickle.dump(self.get_hour, file)
        pickle.dump(self.get_minute, file)

        file.close()
```

This is the button:

```
set_streak_btn = tk.Button(self, bg="medium purple", text="Add",
                                    command=lambda: Streak.set_streak)
```

Comment: You have a lot of questions here. It'd be better to focus on one (or at most a few very related) questions in your post.

Comment: You can get the current contents of an `Entry` widget by calling its `get()` method (and then pickle that string).

Comment: Use `pickle.load(...)` to load the saved data.  For running two commands, try `command=lambda: (func1(), func2())`.